# WebRTC Empty string in iceCandidate

Tags: webrtc

I am seeing these iceCandidates:

```
[{"candidate":"","sdpMid":"audio","sdpMLineIndex":0,"usernameFragment":"f18ab8e6"}]
```

```
[{"candidate":"","sdpMid":"0","sdpMLineIndex":0,"usernameFragment":"b06cfb12"}]
```

Namely, candidate field is empty string. It's not that empty cadidate which means, no more candidates are comming, this is normal iceCandidate object except it doesn't have the candidate field. How is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is valid and emitted by Firefox, Chrome does not implement it yet (but should be silently ignoring it when fed into addIceCandidate. It means the ICE engine has finished gathering all candidates it needs for this sdpMid/sdpMLineIndex.

Comment: So Chrome sends null and firefox sends empty string? What about Edge and Safari? Edge is probably same as Chrome, right?

Comment: Firefox will also emit the null candidate in addition. The new Edge will behave as Chrome, Safari mostly like Chrome.